# Python - appending to a pickled list

Tags: python, append, pickle

I'm struggling to append a list in a pickled file.
This is the code:

```
#saving high scores to a pickled file

import pickle

first_name = input("Please enter your name:")
score = input("Please enter your score:")

scores = []
high_scores = first_name, score
scores.append(high_scores)

file = open("high_scores.dat", "ab")
pickle.dump(scores, file)
file.close()

file = open("high_scores.dat", "rb")
scores = pickle.load(file)
print(scores)
file.close()
```

The first time I run the code, it prints the name and score.

The second time I run the code, it prints the 2 names and 2 scores.

The third time I run the code, it prints the first name and score, but it overwrites the second name and score with the third name and score I entered.  I just want it to keep adding the names and scores.  I don't understand why it is saving the first name and overwriting the second one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to pull the list from your database (i.e. your pickle file) first before appending to it.

```
import pickle
import os

high_scores_filename = 'high_scores.dat'

scores = []

# first time you run this, "high_scores.dat" won't exist
#   so we need to check for its existence before we load 
#   our "database"
if os.path.exists(high_scores_filename):
    # "with" statements are very handy for opening files. 
    with open(high_scores_filename,'rb') as rfp: 
        scores = pickle.load(rfp)
    # Notice that there's no "rfp.close()"
    #   ... the "with" clause calls close() automatically! 

first_name = input("Please enter your name:")
score = input("Please enter your score:")

high_scores = first_name, score
scores.append(high_scores)

# Now we "sync" our database
with open(high_scores_filename,'wb') as wfp:
    pickle.dump(scores, wfp)

# Re-load our database
with open(high_scores_filename,'rb') as rfp:
    scores = pickle.load(rfp)

print(scores)
```

Comment: Thank you also for the extra explanation you have provided with the code.

Comment: @dogwynn: Why check if the file exists if you just load to a new variable, and avoid the real issue?

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: I guess I don't know how to call pickle.load from a non-existent file. I know you can do this with DBv2 API modules (e.g. shelve), but I'm not aware of a file-like object (which pickle.load requires) that can be opened in a "create" mode (without creating one).  Otherwise, my goal was to have a script that can be executed repeatedly from the command line, each time adding a new (name,score) tuple.

Comment: @Charlie: My pleasure. Always good to see another Python hacker on the books. :-)

Comment: @dogwynn: mode `ab` instead of `wb` will create a file if one doesn't exist, and append if one does.  Besides, I wasn't suggesting you should try to `load` from a nonexistent file -- merely pointing out that the OP's issue is more generally one of unpicking into an object that has the same name as the existing list -- and thus destroying any edits to the existing list that were made after the `dump`.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I'm not sure how 'ab' is any better than 'wb'. They both create a file if none exists, and you can't append to a pickled object/list the way you would append to a file. The object has to be unpickled, appended to, and re-pickled. The OP's problem was that they were "running the code" (i.e. the whole set of code as a script), and it wasn't behaving correctly. That was because they weren't loading the extant scores before appending new scores. I addressed that.

Comment: @M.D.P Not sure why. That error is usually associated with reading a file object open for writing. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44901902/1869370) for more details.

Answer (score 13):

If you want to write and read to the pickled file, you can call dump multiple times for each entry in your list.  Each time you dump, you append a score to the pickled file, and each time you load you read the next score.

```
>>> import pickle as dill
>>> 
>>> scores = [('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100)]
>>> nscores = len(scores)
>>> 
>>> with open('high.pkl', 'ab') as f:
…   _ = [dill.dump(score, f) for score in scores]
... 
>>> 
>>> with open('high.pkl', 'ab') as f:
...   dill.dump(('mary', 1000), f)
... 
>>> # we added a score on the fly, so load nscores+1
>>> with open('high.pkl', 'rb') as f:
...     _scores = [dill.load(f) for i in range(nscores + 1)]
... 
>>> _scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100), ('mary', 1000)]
>>>
```

The reason your code was failing most likely is that you are replacing the original `scores` with the unpickled list of scores.  So if there were any new scores added, you'd blow them away in memory.

```
>>> scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100)]
>>> f = open('high.pkl', 'wb')
>>> dill.dump(scores, f)
>>> f.close()
>>> 
>>> scores.append(('mary',1000))
>>> scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100), ('mary', 1000)]
>>> 
>>> f = open('high.pkl', 'rb')
>>> _scores = dill.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> _scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100)]
>>> blow away the old scores list, by pointing to _scores
>>> scores = _scores
>>> scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100)]
```

So it's more of a python name reference issue for `scores`, than it is a `pickle` issue.  `Pickle` is just instantiating a new list and calling it `scores` (in your case), and then it garbage collects whatever thing `scores` was pointed to before that.

```
>>> scores = 1
>>> f = open('high.pkl', 'rb')
>>> scores = dill.load(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> scores
[('joe', 1), ('bill', 2), ('betty', 100)]
```

Comment: Thanks also for your input.  dogwynn's solution worked very well but will take on board what you've said.

Comment: WHy is pickle dill here?

Comment: @DheerajMPai: because I use `dill` instead of `pickle`, so that's what I used for my solution. `pickle` also works, so instead of editing my code, I just changed the import.  It's all picking... `dill` is just better at it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt actually answer the question, but if anyone would like to add a single item at a time to a pickle, you can do it by...

```
import pickle
import os

high_scores_filename = '/home/ubuntu-dev/Desktop/delete/high_scores.dat'

scores = []

# first time you run this, "high_scores.dat" won't exist
#   so we need to check for its existence before we load
#   our "database"
if os.path.exists(high_scores_filename):
    # "with" statements are very handy for opening files.
    with open(high_scores_filename,'rb') as rfp:
        scores = pickle.load(rfp)
    # Notice that there's no "rfp.close()"
    #   ... the "with" clause calls close() automatically!

names = ["mike", "bob", "joe"]

for name in names:
    high_score = name
    print(name)
    scores.append(high_score)

# Now we "sync" our database
with open(high_scores_filename,'wb') as wfp:
    pickle.dump(scores, wfp)

# Re-load our database
with open(high_scores_filename,'rb') as rfp:
    scores = pickle.load(rfp)

print(scores)
```

Comment: As denoted by the first 5 words of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use pickle but use h5py which also solves your purpose

```
with h5py.File('.\PreprocessedData.h5', 'a') as hf:
    hf["X_train"].resize((hf["X_train"].shape[0] + X_train_data.shape[0]), axis = 0)
    hf["X_train"][-X_train_data.shape[0]:] = X_train_data

    hf["X_test"].resize((hf["X_test"].shape[0] + X_test_data.shape[0]), axis = 0)
    hf["X_test"][-X_test_data.shape[0]:] = X_test_data


    hf["Y_train"].resize((hf["Y_train"].shape[0] + Y_train_data.shape[0]), axis = 0)
    hf["Y_train"][-Y_train_data.shape[0]:] = Y_train_data

    hf["Y_test"].resize((hf["Y_test"].shape[0] + Y_test_data.shape[0]), axis = 0)
    hf["Y_test"][-Y_test_data.shape[0]:] = Y_test_data
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47074545/9789097)

Comment: Why not use `hickle` or `klepto` instead?  They are both built to give you a simple `dump` and `load` pickle-equivalent syntax for HDF5. If you replace `dill` in my answer with `hickle`, I believe it should work, and store as HDF5.

Comment: Yes, it works. Thanks for the info. I did not know about hickle.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

*

```
import pickle


#adding an empty list to the file
score=[]
with open("high_scores.dat","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(score,f)


def adding_new_score(f_name,score):
    newScore=(f_name,score)

 #reading the file
    with open("high_scores.dat","rb") as f:

 #storing that in a list
        new_score=pickle.load(f)

 #appending to that list
        new_score.append(newScore)

 #again writing the appended list to the file
    with open("high_scores.dat","wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(new_score,f)
 #reading all the scores
    with open("high_scores.dat","rb") as f:
        print(pickle.load(f))
```

`   #whenever a new score comes
first_name = input("Please enter your name:")
score = input("Please enter your score:")
adding_new_score(first_name, score)

```
first_name = input("Please enter your name:")
score = input("Please enter your score:")
adding_new_score(first_name, score)
```

- 

Output:

```
Please enter your name:p
Please enter your score:94
[('p', '94')]
Please enter your name:s
Please enter your score:24
[('p', '94'), ('s', '24')]
```

You can put the ***adding_new_score*** inside a loop, so that every score will be added to the file.

If you are thinking about re-run, if you re-run the program file will became empty again.
Then simply remove

```
score=[]
with open("high_scores.dat","wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(score,f)
```

when you run it 2nd time and further.