# unpickling '_io.BufferedReader' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

Hello everyone I pickled a list of dictionaries to a file using the below code

```
fd = open(file_name,'ab')
for i in listOFDicts:
    pickle.dump(i,fd)
fd.close()
```

Then Now I want to load it using the below code

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as  pickleFile:
    content = pickle.loads(pickleFile)
```

and I get this error "a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BufferedReader'"

when I use load() instead of loads()

I get this error

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc6 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)"

and if I used pickle.load(filename, encoding='latin1')

I get this error
"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bson'"

any help would be really appreciated

Sincerely

Comment: that should work. Are you sure you're not using `loads` instead of `load` ? full traceback please

Comment: I am editing the question and updating it

Comment: you _have_ to use `load`. Why not using `json` to store your dictionaries? using append mode could leave data in the file. Use `wb` to create the file.

Comment: dump a list of dict, don't loop on the dicts. and appending isn't a very good idea. You don't know what was before.

Comment: it might be not a good idea to append ... but its needed .. or you suggest to replace appending by multiple files ? ... and also what is the difference between dumping a list of dicts and looping over the dicts? ... I mean what unicode difference that will make?

Comment: I'd store as a list of dicts. After that, I'd read back the previous list of dicts, append the new dicts to the list and pickle the whole thing... or I'd use `json` so the serialized data is readable (pickle is binary)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code up to show you how to use pickle, edit it to your needs.

```
import pickle

dict = {0:0, 1:1}

list_of_dict = [dict, dict]

with open("save.pickle", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(list_of_dict, f)

del list_of_dict
#print(list_of_dict)
#put below in the other script.
with open("save.pickle", "rb") as f:
    list_of_dict = pickle.load(f)
print(list_of_dict)
```

This was written in python 3, if you are using python 2, change the following lines:

```
import pickle
```

to

```
import cPickle as pickle
```

and change the prints appropriately.

The `del` command was used to delete the variable to save me time from having to write it in 2 scripts. You may ignore that line and then write the remainder in the second script.

Source:
Several of my own python scripts used in past and the following:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

**EDIT:** I've improved the code. Try and use it similarly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

the idea is that I need to append to the file which I did and then I got the errors I mentioned in my questions

it would be appreciated if you could help me go through solving those errors .... 
Sincerely

Comment: In that case you need to load the pickled data first, append to the list, and then pickle dump it again.

Have a look at the answer here to append to existing data:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077573/python-appending-to-a-pickled-list

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre it works, however cPickle is faster. Have a read of the documentation or wiki page I linked in my answer :)